# Hibernate @SQLInsert insert where not exists Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I`m trying to make this work:

```
@SQLInsert(sql =
        "INSERT INTO table" +
                "(colum1,colum2,colum3,colum4,colum5)" +
                "  SELECT ?,?,?,?,?" +
                "  WHERE" +
                "    NOT EXISTS (" +
                        "SELECT id FROM table WHERE " +
                        "colum1 = ? " +
                        "AND colum2 = ? " +
                        "AND colum3 = ? " +
                        "AND colum4 = ? " +
                        "AND colum5 = ? " +
                    ")",
        check = ResultCheckStyle.COUNT)
```

But I'm getting exception:

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 18.
```

And I'm starting to think that this functionality is impossible to be achieved using the @SQLInsert annotation. Witch is unfortunate because should it work it seems pretty clean approach on the issue.

Comment: You can use `insert ... on conflict do nothing` instead (which in addition is safe for concurrent inserts)

Comment: You want us to help you interpret the error? `No value specified for parameter 18` this is your error... you are missing a value for a parameter

Comment: @Mat So it should work if i have all the parameters bound ? Thank you I`ll check this out. Also the parameters are bound from hibernate and I`m not sure if i have any power there.. but i`ll take a look if i missed something

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately this is not an option no unique data in this table, but the requirement is unique rows

Comment: if the data should be unique you should ensure that with a unique constraint or index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i mean the row should be unique like colum1+coulm2+column3 should be unique but i can have a record containing columnN+columN+something diffrent. I`m not sure if thats clear enough :)

Comment: Then create a unique constraint on `(column1, column2, column3)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I actually did not knew i could do that. Thank you I`ll try.